# How to call bash function from script with the same name in the PATH

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script in the PATH, with name foo

that script looks like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

foo_type=`type foo`;

if [[ -z "$foo_type" ]]; then
   . "$HOME/.foo/shell.sh"
fi

'foo' "$@"   ### this calls this script not the bash function in shell.sh
```

the problem as the comment suggests is the 'foo' doesn't call the sourced bash function, it ends up calling the same script and so I get into an infinite loop and I get this error:

```
/.../bin/foo: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

does anyone know how to call the sourced bash function?

Comment: If you have a function or alias, and (in your PATH) a program of the same name, the function/alias takes priority and is executed.

Comment: yeah that seems to be the case, thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what already happens if there's a bash function defined.

The problem in your script is that `foo_type` contains something like `foo is /.../bin/foo` which is not empty, so the script is never sourced and a function is never defined.

You can use `set -x` to debug this and other problems.

Comment: ah yes thanks, you are right, so how can I do a (quick) check to see if it's bash function or just something on the PATH?

Comment: @Olegzandr You could try `type -t foo`, which returns just a single word.

Comment: thanks will try that, although I did realize that if the bash script is reached in the OP, that means the bash function is almost certainly not defined, so I can just always source it